# Send new login & logout logs to a database

Tags: security, logs, php, database, last

I want to know how to send new login and logout logs to a database.

I know that `last` command outputs the "lasts" login info.
But, I found the following problems:

- How to filter to only get new logs? How can I identify them?
- How many time is saved in the `utmp` file? How many time should I wait to refresh it? Should I access `wtmp`? How?
- Is there any other way?
- Can I use `rsyslog.cong` to copy the log info to a MySQL database or to a PHP (local or remote)?

Note that:

- Other users shuold not be able to delete the logs before script/deamon send it to the database.
- Other users should not be able to falsify logs entries.

I'm trying to solve this for several days... Thanks!